# Keyboard and mouse dead after rebooting from live cd to windows

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot

Ubuntu 13.04 live CD was trying to disconnect all USB devices while shutting down and suddenly my power went off.Now when I booted to Windows 7, my usb keyboard and mouse are not working.I tried plugging them back but didn't work.Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting your machine and pressing the key to enter Bios to see if the keyboard itself actually works...  Closing down Ubuntu wont affect hardware on your system, but the power suddenly going out could herald a hardware fault with your computer/motherboard...